# Show subsections of only one section in beamer sidebar

Tags: beamer, sidebar

I have a `beamer` presentation with the following structure:

```
|Section 1
| |-Subsection 1
| |-Subsection 2
|Section 2
| |-Subsection 1
| |-Subsection 2
| |-Subsection 3
| |-Subsection 4
|Section 3
|Section 4
```

I activated `beamer`'s  the sidebar with

```
\useoutertheme[hideallsubsections]{sidebar}
```

but this makes only the sections to be viewed at the side. I wonder if it is possible to show at the sidebar all the sections, but to show also section 2 subsections.

That is, kind of a hybrid between the `default` option for `\useoutertheme{sidebar}` and the `hideallsubsections` option mentioned above:

[image: hidden subsections]

The code:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % suppresses all navigation symbols
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\useoutertheme[width=20mm,hideallsubsections]{sidebar} %
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usecolortheme{default}

\begin{document}
\section{Section1}
\begin{frame}
Hello World
\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection1}
\subsection{Subsection2}
\section{Section2}
\begin{frame}
Lorem ipsum
\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection1}
\subsection{Subsection2}
\subsection{Subsection3}
\section{Section3}
\begin{frame}
Dolor sit amet
\end{frame}
\section{Section4}
\begin{frame}
Nam dui ligula
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Nonetheless I want those hidden subsections to appear at the table of contents!

(To hide the subsections in the screenshot I used Windows Paint)

Comment: The answer is in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/601102/161015. Use `\subsection[]{Subsection1}`, etc. to exclude from the sidebar.

Comment: @Simon Dispa Great! That's exactly what I was looking for. If I am not wrong, the value inside the `[]` bracket is the string to be passed to the sidebar, so I can in effect choose my own heading for this section of subsection, right?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Site moderators, please vote to close this question and mark the answer as "solved in the comments". Or, @SimonDispa, do you want to write an answer?

Comment: I think the comment is  enough.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was answered in the comments.